# Lookup Filter criteria on an object

Tags: lookup

When you have a Lookup Relationship with defined Filter Criteria, you cannot provide a Profile or User with the option to override or neglect this Relationship. If you are using active Integration or you want to perform an initial Data Load for which this Filter Criteria needs to be bypassed, your upload will fail for certain cases. Because the active user doesn't fulfill the criteria defined.

For a User record who performs the Data Migration or Integration, this might become a problem.

Could you please help on this matter as atleast system admin should be able to update the data by ignoring the criteria? Also, remember even if the validation rule is another option,the user will again see lots of unwanted data in lookup filter.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach can be to create a "skip" field (better to keep as checkbox) which is hidden from all page layouts. Add this field to lookup filter criteria, to skip filtering logic if "skip = TRUE". Only system admin/ integration user profile should have access to this field. While uploading data mark this field as "TRUE", which will skip lookup filter for the system admin/ integration user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Add filter logic to build two different ways the filter can evaluate to true. As long as the formula evaluates to true, then the value can be selected. In this case, I have my real filter and then another one that checks the user's profile. Either one can be true.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When you create the 'filter' criteria, there is a radio button for 'Filter Type'.  Choose the 'Optional' selection.